# App to quickly and easily transfer small amount of data from Windows to Android

Tags: windows, android, data, wifi, data-transfer

I'm looking for an app to **quickly and easily** transfer a small amount of data from Windows to Android.  It would be great if it also worked in the other direction.

By "small amount of data", I mean under 250 bytes.

Ideally, I could just copy something to the clipboard and then tell the app to transfer the clipboard contents to the other device.  But using the clipboard is not a requirement.

- I don't want to use something heavy like Dropbox or even email.
- Encryption is not required.
- Transfer can be by WiFi, Bluetooth, sound, or camera, or any other means.
- Prefer gratis, but it's not a requirement.

Comment: Not tried any of those (hence I cannot write an answer), but there are several [cross-device Clipboards](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_clipboard#group_43) available. Some work via ADB, some via the "local network" (matching your WiFi requirement), some require a companion desktop app. All of them are available "for free", some are even FOSS and available on F-Droid.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest an arbitrary combination of a Windows QR code generator (that can encode arbitrary portions of text) and an Android QR code reader app. I use this combination for exactly the same purpose, for quickly transferring small amounts of data from a PC to a mobile device.

The only requirement from the question that is not fulfilled by this is

> Transfer can be by WiFi or Bluetooth, with a preference for WiFi.

However, I see a fair chance that the OP simply did not think of "screen + camera" as another data transfer technology available in the target setting.

As a concrete suggestion for the Windows/generation side, there is [QR Code Generator](https://www.heise.de/download/product/portable-qr-code-generator-85046) (website in German, sorry, but I *presume* the software will display English texts, as well), which I find easy to use. However, there are certainly quite some more, at latest when you include web-based services.

On the Android side, one of the many available QR code readers is [QR Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=la.droid.qr&hl=en). You can use it to scan various QR code content types; plain text read from a QR code will be readily displayed, and can also be copied via the clipboard into other apps.

Comment: You're absolutely right regarding your "fair chance" statement!  I'll update the question accordingly.